# Google OAuth consent screen not showing app Logo and Name

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Recently we noticed that our app OAuth consent screen does not show Logo and Name of application. Instead, it shows the redirect URL.
And there is no Terms and Privacy that we provided in developers console.

---

[image]

---

This is how our OAuth consent screen is setup:

---

[image]

Can some one please tell what we are doing wrong?

Comment: I've never try with other fields than owner email & product name.
Got the same problem than you, no logo or policy displaying on consent screen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We [made some of these changes](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-developer-identity-guidelines.html) to respond to the OAuth phishing. These changes were done in a short time so it applies to all apps. The redirect domain shows the real place the token will be sent (vs. the name was not verified and could have been anything).  We understand that this impact some app. We are working in improving it so apps that are verified/reviewed will have their name/logo displayed.

Update (Oct 1, 2017): You can now [submit a review](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification) for existing app and after the review, we'll show the name of the app. Please indicate clearly that you want the review to have the name and/or displayed (instead of URL).

Comment: Thanks for the info, do you have any ETA for when you'll finish ?

Comment: Hard to give an exact ETA but it will be few months before most of the infrastructure work is done. After that,  we'll plan to star to reviewing the top apps (based on user volume) and take requests from developers who would like to get this review/exemption.

Comment: How do we get our apps/api credentials reviewed? Let's say we have a webapp with oAuth using auth0.

Comment: We are still working on these.  I haven't looked whether it is possible with auth0 or not but in most cases when you use a third party the right thing is to have a subdomain in your site and that traffic should be sent to 3rd party. e.g. you could have oauthreturn.mysite.com as the redirect url and that domian should point to auth0. In this case the approval page will show mysite.com

Comment: how can we show our product name instead of domain name like before?

Comment: The domain name is the only thing possible right now. As I mentioned we are working on changes to allow that but it is few months away.

Comment: @nvagr "few months away" is now here - any update on this?

Comment: Yes, if you go file a review ticket for an existing app, after the review is done, the consent page will show the app name. https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification

Comment: @nvnagr I have tried to submit a review 2 times now. Every time, the reply is that my scopes do not need to be reviewed. I use profile and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly scopes. I still want to be reviewed to be able to have the correct product name to show up instead of my developer email. Any recommendations on what I'm supposed to do? I my local dev environment, the real product name shows up.

Comment: @nvnagr I submitted for review and got the "inapplicable for verification process" message as well. I want the calendar read only scope and want to show my organisation name/URL instead of the third party OAuth redirect URL I am using.

Comment: When I fill the form it said >>For less than 5 users, you don't need to fill this form. See the instructions at the top of this form to test your app or for personal use.
But my site is already verified via search console.

Comment: Please submit the review again and clearly mention in the comment that you are requesting the review to display the app name or to display the icon.

Comment: @nvnagr I followed the link `https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification` you provided, it brought me to the consent screen tab, but it doesn't work for Internal app at all. My application type is `Internal` where I'm only allowing users from my organization. The page says `Verification is required if your app is marked as Public`, so that means my app doesn't require verification (and I don't see the `submit for verification` button as well). However, my app logo is still not displayed in the popout window. How can I enable to show the logo for internal app?

Comment: The process has changed. Now you can submit for verification in developer console. That is where you need to mark it internal vs external.

Comment: Following the trail of messages seems that the process is still not so clear. Let's state that I've an application with a consent screen which has already been reviewed and approved in the past. If I have to implement another auth flow with a new client id, will my users be able to see the adeguate product name ? If not, will the review be needed again ? What if I'm using a restricted scope ? what if no scope changes ?

Comment: @nvnagr I submitted my App for approval, but I need the App Name and Client ID in my OAuth Consent screen, how would I do that if I have to get my App verified before it shows on the consent screen?