# Google OAuth consent screen not showing app Logo only shows domain name

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

We are using oauth API for google sign in and configured app logo in https://console.developers.google.com. Also Submitted the app review form and domain verification. Still logo is not appearing in consent screen.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Google now requires [developers to request verification of their app](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification) before they will show the logo.

See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138213/google-oauth-consent-screen-not-showing-app-logo-and-name) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Verification is not required if the App is for internal use. "After you upload a logo, you will need to submit your app for verification unless the app is configured for internal use only or has a publishing status of "Testing""

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please note that your answer better would have been a comment on Pauls answer :)