# Authorised domain being displayed on my Google OAuth consent screen, instead of App Name

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

[Screenshot #1 - Screenshot of My Google Cloud Console with App Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykM8T.png)

[Screenshot #2 - Screenshot of how my Authorised domain is being displayed on Google OAuth consent screen - Instead of APP NAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjZbX.png)

**Help required**

1. I am submitting an application for Google OAuth where my application has been rejected because the Google OAuth consent screen is showing the `authorized domain` instead of the `app name` - please refer to screenshot #2.
2. The `app name` on my Google Cloud Console for this app, within the relevant project is the app name I would like to be displayed on the OAuth consent screen. Please refer to screenshot #1.
3. Lastly, I am unable to understand why my `app logo` is also not being displayed on the Google OAuth consent screen.

Why is this happening? I tried looking through various forums and I could only find similar issues being dated back to 2017/2018 where people had faced this problem, nothing from recent years - 2020/2021 - link here - [Google OAuth consent screen not showing app Logo and Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138213/google-oauth-consent-screen-not-showing-app-logo-and-name)

Comment: I have same incident

Comment: I am also having the same issue but I guess it will be after verification which takes around 4-6 weeks time. If found something will update or add an aswers.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I believe this gets resolved once your app is verified.

I think they show the domain for un-verified apps now to prevent phishing attempts (e.g. your domain is sampleapp.com but you put a display name of [CredibleBusiness] instead of SampleApp).

Read more here:
[Google OAuth consent screen not showing app Logo and Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138213/google-oauth-consent-screen-not-showing-app-logo-and-name)