# Google One Tap prompt showing domain name instead of application name

Tags: google-signin, google-one-tap

The Google One Tap prompt is showing `Sign in to <domain name> with Google` instead of `Sign in to <application name> with Google`. It was able to show the application name when I was working on localhost, but when I tried to deploy on a staging environment, only the domain name was showing.

Might this be related to the Google application publish status still in `Testing`? Or the domain not yet verified in the Google Search Console? Do note that the application only requires non-sensitive scopes, if that helps.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138213/google-oauth-consent-screen-not-showing-app-logo-and-name